# Using ejs with express returns unexpected token < used

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

this is my first try at using Ejs, i think i got all my syntax right. cant understand whats wrong

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
let today = new Date();
let options = {
  weekday: "long",
  year: "numeric",
  month: "long",
  day: "numeric"
};

let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
let todoList = ["Sleep","Eat","?"];
app.get("/", function(req, res){
 res.render("index", {
   day: day,
   todoList: todoList
 } );
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
  let newInput = req.body.todoInput;
  todoList.push(newInput);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

my ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ra's To-do List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <%= day %> : Today's to-do list</p>
  <ul>
     <% for (var i=0, i< todoList.length, i++) { %>
    <li> <%= todoList[i] %> </li>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="todoInput" placeholder="Add to your to-do list here">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Add stuff to-do</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Im using WSL and have installed all the modules properly. it gives the unexpected token < in .... while compiling ejs. ive been at this for a couple of hours now and i might break my laptop soon :)

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in
>   /mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/views/index.ejs while
>   compiling ejs
>
> If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
>   https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an
>   async function, pass async: true as an option.
>       at new Function ()
>       at Template.compile (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:618:12)
>       at Object.compile (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:389:16)
>       at handleCache (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:212:18)
>       at tryHandleCache (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:251:16)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:482:10)
>       at View.render (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)

Comment: please post the complete error stack for quick understanding of the problem

Comment: @kRiZ  
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in /mnt/c/Users/PraveshRana/Desktop/webDev/ejs-todo/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs

Comment: use semicolons ( ; ) instead of commas ( , ) in for loop

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is just that you are using commas instead of semi-colons in your ejs statement.

So instead of:

```
<% for (var i=0, i< todoList.length, i++) { %>
```

It should be:

```
<% for (var i=0; i< todoList.length; i++) { %>
```

Cheers,
Aidan.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, "<" less than symbol. Because you can not use on html. You should change html entity, like "& lt;"(delete one space char). And check it google another html entity symbol. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (similar) error in my node-ejs app (`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; ...`). I think general answer for this error is to check your **ejs** code carefully. Usually there is a syntax error in your codes. For me, I noticed that when I used ejs variables in my code (for example `<%= email %>` that **email** is a variable), I used the wrong syntax like this:

```
<% email =%>
```

And after correcting that, the error disappeared. The text shown in this error is somehow **illusory** in my opinion. The problem actually is not related to `async function` and usually the character mentioned in `token <` or `token ;` or ... is not related to the **real** syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because of long string get break, when I use a HTML formatter

```
<td style="padding-left: 1rem">
    <%= dateFns.format(new Date(date), 'long string format date' ) %>
</td>
```

when formatter is applied

```
<td style="padding-left: 1rem">
    <%= dateFns.format(new Date(date), 'long string 
format date' ) %>
</td>
```

my solution is to have a variable for the date format string

```js
DATE_FORMAT = 'long string format date'
ejs.render('template.html', {...data, DATE_FORMAT})
```

```
<td style="padding-left: 1rem">
    <%= dateFns.format(new Date(date),DATE_FORMAT  ) %>
</td>
```